# Convert bitmap to Grayscale

Tags: android, android-glide, android-bitmap, grayscale

In my application i want to upload an image to server but i want to convert it to gray scale before i do that.< br />
So i found a function that takes a bitmap and returns a bitmap as Gray scale.

```
fun getGrayScale(src: Bitmap): Bitmap {

        //Custom color matrix to convert to GrayScale
        val matrix = floatArrayOf(
            0.3f,
            0.59f,
            0.11f,
            0f,
            0f,
            0.3f,
            0.59f,
            0.11f,
            0f,
            0f,
            0.3f,
            0.59f,
            0.11f,
            0f,
            0f,
            0f,
            0f,
            0f,
            1f,
            0f
        )

        val dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.width, src.height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)

        val canvas = Canvas(dest)
        val paint = Paint()
        val filter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix)
        paint.colorFilter = filter
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0.toFloat(), 0.toFloat(), paint)

        return dest
    }
```

That runs successfully but NOT in Android 10, in which i get the following exception

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:298)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps
        at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.onHwBitmapInSwMode(BaseCanvas.java:632)
        at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfHwBitmapInSwMode(BaseCanvas.java:639)
        at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(BaseCanvas.java:73)
        at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseCanvas.java:113)
        at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1540)
        at com.example.utilities.ImageUtils.getGrayScale(ImageUtils.kt:64)
        at com.example.utilities.FileUtils.imageRefactor(FileUtils.kt:98)
        at com.example.workmanager.FileSplitterWorker.doWork(FileSplitterWorker.kt:54)
        at androidx.work.CoroutineWorker$startWork$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutineWorker.kt:68)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)
```

I have tried to add hardwareAccelerated as true in my manifest but same happens.
Can i do this with Glide, or with another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android O they have introduced new `Bitmap.Config` the `Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE` which is an actual optimization when it comes to draw the `Bitmap` to the screen. So since you are using Software rendering that is why you get the error.

Try this:

```
fun getGrayScaleBitmap(original: Bitmap): Bitmap {
    // You have to make the Bitmap mutable when changing the config because there will be a crash
    // That only mutable Bitmap's should be allowed to change config.
    val bmp = original.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
    val bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.width, bmp.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bmpGrayscale)
    val paint = Paint()
    val colorMatrix = ColorMatrix()
    colorMatrix.setSaturation(0f)
    val colorMatrixFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix)
    paint.colorFilter = colorMatrixFilter
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0F, 0F, paint)
    return bmpGrayscale
}
```

This will replace the `Bitmap.Config` from `Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE` to `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`.

Hope it helps!!!